# Как сменить заголовок в браузере?

Tags: joomla

Всем привет, как сменить название в joomla. В обычном html это можно сделать в title, а как сделать это в joomla?

Answer (score 1):

В шаблоне? 
Joomla >= 1.5

```
<?php
    $this->setTitle( 'My site title' );
    ?>
```

Comment: а в joomle 3.0